# Speak Here ported to to Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I would like to know if there's an example code somewhere about porting the speak here example code for iPhone to the Mac.

What I basically want to do is register the sound of the user from the microphone and play it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Speak Here" uses Audio Queue Services for recording and playback. AQ Services is a pure C framework that can be used from Cocoa. It is available on the Mac since 10.5.

If you want to use Audio Queues on the Mac, this sample code might be a good starting point:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioQueueTools/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004380

On 10.7 you can also use the Cocoa framework AVFoundation. It provides higher abstraction and makes writing a simple record/playback app pretty easy.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html

For 10.6 you could look into [QTKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCocoaObjCKit/_index.html).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't seem to be able to record from the microphone using qtkit. Here's what I did so far (taken from another project where I was recording from the camera: http://pastie.org/2377144 ). That produces a file which can't be read by VLC at all, so I guess this is not the correct way to do it. I've been looking into the AQ services sample codes but most of them are in C++ and I have no idea how to integrate them in my Objective c code. I thought it was simple to register from the microphone and play straight away!